# Запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация, разговорная-речь, диалог

Вопрос про "или" №2

Ставится ли запятая перед "или"? Нужна ли она тут?

Привет, Миша. Хорошо, что зашёл. Располагайся... Зашёл часы отремонтировать(,) или так, поболтать?

Здравствуй, Юра. Ты по делу(,) или по стаканчику?

О, а это галоши(,) или же изделие №4.

Comment: В конце третьего предложения нет никакого знака. Какой-то ведь должен быть, правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая перед "или" нужна в двух последних предложениях (по разным причинам).

В первом "или" предоставляет нам выбор цели прихода:

*Привет, Миша. Хорошо, что зашёл. Располагайся... Зашёл часы отремонтировать или так, поболтать?*

*О, а это галоши, или же изделие №4.* То есть "изделие № 4" в фабричном эээ... прейскуранте и означает магазинно-обывательские галоши.

*Здравствуй, Юра. Ты по делу, или (жахнем) по стаканчику?* -

ССП, две основы.